# Drupal video event Google Tag Manager

Tags: drupal

I've an Drupal application, and a GTM container used to trigger event. Everything works fine but one, the video YouTube one. Is there a specific configuration to do in order for the event to be triggered? Something useful to know ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for youtube player events like play, pause, end.
if that is the case here is link for you:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference